Later you let me know what she says or said
if I tell friend A to ask friend B whether or not she is interested in having a cup of coffee with us and want to know her answer, should I say "later you let me know what she says or said" to friend A? I am sorry if I have asked a question that has an obvious answer ... Thank you!

"Later" is unnecessary - if A hasn't asked B yet, obviously they won't be able to tell you her answer until later. "Let me know what she says" is the most natural, but "said" would be acceptable.

You let me know later what she says. You can use later if you want to.

That's not correct.  You have a number of options:

Say nothing, because it is clear from context.  If you ask friend A to ask something to friend B, it's probably obvious that you want to know what friend A replies. You probably don't need to spell this out.
Use an expression like "Let me know what she says"  You don't need "later" (of course it must be later)  You don't need  "says or said" though either would be possible
Express your desire, and let the friend work out how to fulfil it "I'd like to know if friend B wants to have coffee with us".  You allow friend A to work out how to make your wish come true (by asking friend B and telling you the answer) if they want.


Thank you so much !
